# how to make hr tag not visible on the textbox

Tags: html, css

This is my site:http://vani.valse.com.my/schone_lightings/index.php
I don't want the `<hr>` tag to appear on top of the textbox and submit button under class="subscribe". I tried setting z-index higher for the subscribe class, but it doesn't help!

HTML

```
<div class="hide-for-small-only hide-for-medium-only  line_wrapper"><!--start of line bg div-->
    <hr class="hr_tag"/>
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 large-centered columns subscribe">
                    <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-10 columns">
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your email address for newsletter subscription"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-2 columns">
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div><!--end of line bg div-->
```

CSS

```
.line_wrapper
{
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    position: relative;

}
.subscribe
{
z-index: 60;
}

.subscribe input[type="submit"]

{

    background-color:#000;

    color:#fff;

    border: 1px solid #000;

    padding:10px;

    height: 50px;


}

.subscribe input[type="text"]

{



    color:#000;

    padding:10px;

    height:50px;

}
.hr_tag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: where do you want the `hr` to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you applied `background line image` on top div and you gave `opacity:0.9` to `row div`.
So because of that background image of line is visible on `textbox and button`. OR you can do remove opacity only for textbox and button or else remove middle portion of your line image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the styling for hr_tag as an absolutely positioned element will 'layer' above regular static content.

```
/* position: absolute; */
/* z-index: 50; */
/* top: 10px; */
/* right: 0; */
/* left: 0; */
```

Comment: I want it to be where it is right now but just not be visible on the textbox and submit button.I mean the z-index should be lesser than them.

Answer (score 0):

Rmove inline Background-Image property from

```
<div style="**background-image: url('img/line.png')**;background-repeat: repeat-x;z-index: 50;" class="line"><!--start of line bg div-->
    <!--<hr class="hr_tag"/>-->
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-10 small-centered medium-6 large-centered columns subscribe">
                    <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-10 columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address for newsletter subscription" value=""> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-2  columns">
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```